# Laravel backend, Angular2 on another server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I drew up this flowchart to explain but its all over complicated.

I just cant wrap my head around how this will work.

Front end : Server 1 - Angular2 
Back end  : Server 2 - Laravel 5.3

At the moment the back end has an auth token enabled with the passport.

I can fetch and send any info where I enable the Middleware API.

But how do I set up a Middleware API for the front end of the website to access and 
a different one for user profiles? 
Or do I not require this? Do I just render all data requested from the site in JSON and
make the Angular2 front end render it. Then with the Authentication when a user logs in 
send back a token instead of a session.

I would love if anyone knows of any tutorials of Laravel 5.3 back end with
Angular2 front end on another server.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the correct workflow in you case would be:

- A user logs in, you send a request to the laravel server requesting a token
- This token is stored in the session and will be used for future requests.
- Angular will render the responses based on the requests made.

So, you say:

> But how do I set up a Middleware API for the front end of the website to access and a different one for user profiles?

Well, because they are on different server, the view on this case will be rendered just by angular, you should find a way to make permission so the UI will know what to dow. In this case, you can not put an auth middleware to "block" access to the view, because the view will be rendered by a different thing other than larave.